# How to stop TextToSpeech from speaking the given message

Tags: app-inventor

In MIT App Inventor, there is a media component called [TextToSpeech](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/media.html). It has a method called `Speak(text message)`, which speaks a given message.

However it has no method to stop speaking. Imagine when the message is long, it can keep speaking for a long time, which is not desirable.

Wonder if there is a good way to ask TextToSpeech to stop speaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way to ask TextToSpeech to stop speaking is to call TextToSpeech's method `Speak(text message)` again, with an empty text. As a result, TextToSpeech will stop speaking immediately.

Here is an example. Suppose that TextToSpeech1's `Speak` method has already been called to start speaking a long message. Now click Button1, and in its event handler you can call TextToSpeech1's method `Speak(text message)` with an empty text, as shown below. TextToSpeech1 will stop speaking right away.

[image]

**Note** on the App Inventor version I'm working with:

```
Built: September 27 2019 Version: nb180
Use Companion: 2.55 or 2.55u or 2.55 or 2.55uu
Target Android SDK: 28 (Android 9.0 Pie)
```